# Keybindings with AltGr

Tags: key-bindings

Is there any way to bind a command to a key combination like `AltGr-f`?

The reason I ask is the following:  I use the “US international” keyboard layout (on Linux), which remaps the right Alt key to AltGr (aka Level3 shift), so that I can type certain accented characters I need. But this keyboard layout also has the nice side-effect of making some new (and very convenient) key combinations available; for instance, `AltGr-t` inserts þ, which I never use, so I can rebind it to something else.  The problem is that `AltGr-f` inserts an f, and not some useless symbol, so I can't bind that key to a command (similar issue with the characters g, h, b).  I know I could use xmodmap to assign some random symbol to `AltGr-f`, but is there a pure Emacs way to do that?

Comment: I suspect that's not possible since Emacs just receives keysyms. So, since `AltGr` is no modifier (it enables the third level map), Emacs just gets the generated keysyms like `þ` which you can inspect with `F1 k þ`.

Comment: Actually, X provides both the keysym and the keycode to the client, but I don't know if Emacs can bind a command to a keycode.  It's certainly possible to remap `AltGr-f` to a different keysym at the xkb level.

Comment: Shouldn't you add a tag for the platform you're on? AltGr obviously doesn't apply to OS X, and the way the OS affects the way AltGr is generated/intercepted/caught might be different on Linux, Windows and other operating systems.

Comment: @wasamasa That sounds right, but on the other hand there is the `key-translation-map` and similar stuff that seem to work at a lower level and might know about AltGr.

Comment: Not an answer but hopefully some approximation -- use the compose key.
That is after doing (something like) $ setxkbmap -option compose:menu the menu key will now behave like a compose key After that use something like [pointless-xcompose](https://github.com/rrthomas/pointless-xcompose/) as a starting point to set up your own compose sequences.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just bind these characters to commands you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

*No.* `AltGr` isn't a modifier known to Emacs.

*Yes.* Emacs knows more modifiers than `Control`, `Meta` and `Shift`: `Hyper` and `Super`.

What you have to do is tell our OS or window system that the key/scan code generated by pressing the key labelled `[AltGr]` is "Super". I haven't done that in a while, but inspecting my own xkb (for X11) configuration this would probably look like this:

```
key <RALT> { [ Super_L ] };
key <SUPR> { [ NoSymbol, Super_L ] };
modifier_map Mod4 { <SUPR> };
```

Unfortunately you cannot just drop that into a file and toggle a switch somewhere and it just works. Xkb is a monstrosity and you will have to learn how to tame it. Unfortunately no decent user documentation exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I use the CLI Emacs over X, but this might still be helpful for someone. I don't know of a pure Emacs way but I know what I did to fix this.

I prefer UK layout, but keystrokes like M-x are difficult.
`loadkeys` loads keymaps on the fly.

Messing around, I found the `linux-with-two-alt-keys.inc` file.
For a UK layout with both two Alt keys:

```
$ loadkeys /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/uk.map.gz /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-with-two-alt-keys.inc
```

I could have stopped and chucked that in `.bash_profile`, but I am petty.

I tried editing `/etc/rc.conf` which alters the bootup keymap, but I was couldn't get both keymaps recognised.

(Note, I am on Void Linux; the file changes between distros. `/etc/vconsole.conf` on Fedora, `/etc/rc.local` on Ubuntu, I believe)

So I gave up and made my own keymap. Less scary than it sounds.
I copied and decompressed `uk.map.gz`, adding:

```
keycode 100 = Alt
```

Before compressing, saving as `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/custom.map.gz`, and editing `rc.conf`:

```
KEYMAP=custom
```

Both Alt and AltGr now both work as Alt in CLI Emacs.