# How can I press a key combination including CTRL and ALT_GR on a Swedish keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, keyboard-layout

I am running Emacs (26.1 - build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) on Windows 10 and I cannot type any key combination including CTRL and ALT_GR on my swedish keyboard.

I stumbled on this when I tried to use the C-M-\ (indent-region). But after some testing it seems the problem occurs with any combination including CTRL and ALT_GR.
Alot of characters on the Swedish keyboard is mapped to ALT_GR combinations, e.g. to type $ I press ALT_GR-4 and for \ I press ALT_GR-+.

So in Emacs CTRL-h k gives this result:

- CTRL-$ (CTRL-ALT_GR-4) => "$ runs the command self-insert-command..."
- CTRL-META-$ (CTRL-ALT-ALT_GR-4) => "M-$ runs the command ispell-word..."
- CTRL-\ (CTRL-ALT_GR-+) => "\ runs the command self-insert-command..."
- CTRL-META-\ (CTRL-ALT-ALT_GR-+)"M-\ runs the command delete-horizontal-space..."

So it seems like the CTRL key is lost when ALT_GR is also pressed.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try temporarily switching to a layout without an alt gr key and test how Emacs behaves when you use the right alt key in combinations to rule out key jamming problems with your keyboard?

Comment: Changing to english layout doesn't seem to change the behaviour. Right-alt-a prints the character á, and CTRL-Right-alt-a also prints á.

Comment: The answer to this question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/keybindings-with-altgr?rq=1 says that emacs cannot recognize alt-gr. But I don't know if this is applicable to my problem.

Comment: This is probably not an emacs problem. If I change to english keyboard layout and press the keys alt_gr-a and ctrl-alt_gr-a in notepad they both print á. So it's more likely some issue with the keyboard or keymapping on the Asus laptop I am using. Any suggestions on how I can fix this is appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here with Emacs 27.1 on Windows 10 with a French keyboard. It works for me if:
- press AltGr **first** and keep it pressed during the whole sequence
- use CTRL key **on the right side of the space bar** C-} is obtained by: AltGr pressed during the whole sequence, rightCTRL-} C-M-@ is obtained by : AltGr pressed during the whole sequence, rightCTRL-M-@ C-M-\ is obtained by : AltGr pressed during the whole sequence, rightCTRL-M-\ Inspired by solution 1 of https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AltGrKey (I wanted to post it as a comment, but not enough reputation for that.)